# reorder specific DIVs with "transform" style property

Tags: javascript

I have a list of DIVs that shows a contact list, some of these DIVs randomly might have a specific `online` class name.

I want to change the `translateY` value of the `transform` style property to push the `online` contacts to the top above the others.

My current scenario is like:

```
<div id="list">
    <div class="contact" style="transform: translateY(0px)">Contact 1</div>
    <div class="contact" style="transform: translateY(50px)">Contact 2</div>
    <div class="contact online" style="transform: translateY(100px)">Contact 3</div>
    <div class="contact" style="transform: translateY(150px)">Contact 4</div>
    <div class="contact online" style="transform: translateY(200px)">Contact 5</div>
    <div class="contact online" style="transform: translateY(250px)">Contact 6</div>
    <div class="contact" style="transform: translateY(300px)">Contact 7</div>
</div>
```

What should happen after running my pure JavaScript function is pushing contact 3, 5 and 6 to the top above the orders, and the new DOM should be like:

```
<div id="list">
    <div class="contact" style="transform: translateY(150px)">Contact 1</div>
    <div class="contact" style="transform: translateY(200px)">Contact 2</div>
    <div class="contact online" style="transform: translateY(0px)">Contact 3</div>
    <div class="contact" style="transform: translateY(250px)">Contact 4</div>
    <div class="contact online" style="transform: translateY(50px)">Contact 5</div>
    <div class="contact online" style="transform: translateY(100px)">Contact 6</div>
    <div class="contact" style="transform: translateY(300px)">Contact 7</div>
</div>
```

Now, I should see the contact list reordered as the DIVs that have the `online` class have a new `translateY` value.

Here is what I tried:

```
var contacts = document.getElementsByClassName("online");
    for(var i = 0; i < contacts.length; i++)
    {
        var current = contacts[i].style.transform;
        contacts[i].style.transform = "translateY(0px)";
        var mainElements = document.getElementsByClassName("contact");


        mainElements[i].style.webkitTransform = current;
        mainElements[i].style.MozTransform = current;
        mainElements[i].style.msTransform = current;
        mainElements[i].style.OTransform = current;
        mainElements[i].style.transform = current;


        console.log('current element transform', current);
        console.log('current element transform after change', slides[i].style.transform);
        console.log('first element', mainElements[i].style.transform);
        //value is not changing to the new value, it remains 0 --^

    }
```

I think the code is clear, that is what I tried for a long time to do, I know I am doing something wrong but I couldn't find where exactly.

Note: I know there are lots of other ways to reorder the items, like moving the whole node or with using jQuery or other stuff, but for some reasons I don't want any other method different that the one I am using, pure JavaScript and changing translateY value (Just in case someone will try to advice me with other methods).

I hope I can find some help here.

Thanks.

Comment: If your ordering needs are purely for presentation purposes, have you looked at flexbox's `order` property? Works like a charm. Note that this will maintain your original HTML structure. With `order` and JS you could directly associate an array position with an order number, saving you from fooling with transform and pixels and such.

Comment: Thank you, I already mentioned, I need to stick to the question, using translateY.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It can be done way easier without translate, but since you said in other answer you have to stick to the translate, here is function for you

```
function orderByOnline() {

    // Select all contants
    const allContacts = document.querySelectorAll(".contact");

    // Prepare arrays where you will add online and offline contacts
    let onlineContacts = [], notOnlineContacts = [];

    // Use spread operator on query selector and use filter function
    // to check if contact has class online - means he is online
    [...allContacts].filter(function(contact) {
        if (contact.classList.contains("online")) {
            onlineContacts.push(contact); 
        } else {
            notOnlineContacts.push(contact)
        }
    });

    // Now parse throu online contacts, start from 0 because variable
    // i will be used to determine translate value
    for (let i = 0; i < onlineContacts.length; i++) {
        const translateValue = i * 50;
        onlineContacts[i].style.transform = `translateY(${translateValue}px)`;
    }

    // Sort offline contacts, but starting point has to be length of online contacts
    // so you can get proper values
    for (let i = onlineContacts.length; i < notOnlineContacts.length; i++) {
        const translateValue = i * 50;
        notOnlineContacts[i].style.transform = `translateY(${translateValue}px)`;   
    }
}
```

Comment: You answer worked great on my scenario, thank you very much you made my day.

Answer (score 2):

Try following js

```js
let d= document.querySelector('#list').children;

let ds=[...d].sort((a,b)=> [...b.classList].includes('online') ? 1 : -1 )

ds.map( (x,i)=> x.style.transform=`translateY(${i*50}px)`)
```

```css
#list div {
  position: absolute; /* I add this style to prettify output */
}
```

```html
<div id="list">
    <div class="contact" style="transform: translateY(0px)">Contact 1</div>
    <div class="contact" style="transform: translateY(50px)">Contact 2</div>
    <div class="contact online" style="transform: translateY(100px)">Contact 3</div>
    <div class="contact" style="transform: translateY(150px)">Contact 4</div>
    <div class="contact online" style="transform: translateY(200px)">Contact 5</div>
    <div class="contact online" style="transform: translateY(250px)">Contact 6</div>
    <div class="contact" style="transform: translateY(300px)">Contact 7</div>
</div>
```

Or remove translate and use pure CSS approach

```css
#list {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.contact {
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  order: 2;
}

.online {
  order:1
}
```

```html
<div id="list">
    <div class="contact" >Contact 1</div>
    <div class="contact" >Contact 2</div>
    <div class="contact online">Contact 3</div>
    <div class="contact" >Contact 4</div>
    <div class="contact online" >Contact 5</div>
    <div class="contact online" >Contact 6</div>
    <div class="contact">Contact 7</div>
</div>
```

Comment: That's a good simple answer I like it, sorry I cannot accept 2 answers but it really looks cool to use. Thanks!